# I am unable to fix these Errors during MAUI Installation

Tags: visual-studio, installation, maui, visual-studio-2022

Can you figure it out what the problem is?

I have tried some fixes but still the problem exists.

```
Fix failed - Workload Install failed: `dotnet workload install --sdk-version 6.0.100-preview.7.21379.14 --no-cache
--disable-parallel android-aot ios maccatalyst tvos macos maui wasm-tools --skip-manifest-update --source
"https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" --source
"https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/dnceng/public/_packaging/6.0.100-preview.7.21379.14-shipping-1/nuget/v3/index.json"`
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────


! There were one or more problems detected.

Please review the errors and correct them and run maui-check again.
```

Comment: There are a couple of issues on [the repository](https://github.com/dotnet/maui) describing this you might ant to check out. Or maybe even better; the maui-check repository :) Also, this needs more detail on what the actual errors are if we want to say something useful about it

Comment: i have fixed the issues with installation, but now i don't see MAUI in visual studio project types.

Comment: @hotspot use commandline or install this [3rd party extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=egvijayanand.maui-templates)